ADF csv file as output not wokring when using copy task
I am using a copy task and then delete to simulate a mov task since there isn't on in ADF. I have a .CSV as source but when I copy it across as a .csv the job doesnt work, if I leave the default setting which is .txt or blank it does work but its saves it as .txt which is not what I want. Seems like a big with ADF but essentially I want a csv as out as it is as source.



ADF csv file as output not wokring when using copy task

File extension must be specified when the fileName is not specified in the output Delimited Text dataset .txt,.csv.
When file name is configured in the output dataset, it will be used as the sink file name and the file extension setting will be ignored.
When you use .csv source file it will copy source file as it is with name you don't need to configure file name in the output dataset
Source Dataset:

Sink Dataset:

Output:

